# NavigationManager в Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

я пытаюсь использовать NavigationManager.NavigateTo ("...") в Blazor WebAssembly C#, и, согласно многим источникам, это правильно, но IDE показывает ошибку и говорит, что для нестатических методов мне нужно создать экземпляр этого класса. Буду признателен любой помощи в решении этой проблемы.

Comment: Вам надо сделать inject на страницу где хотите использовать

Answer (score 1):

Если вы пытаетесь использовать навигатор в компоненте или на странице, то необходимо сначала получить его с помощью инъекции:

```
@inject NavigationManager Navigation
```

Затем уже вы сможете использовать его для перенаправлений в вашем коде:

```
Navigation.NavigateTo("...")
```